# python dictionaries and map functions

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-redshift

Am trying to insert a query into redshift via python code. It is throwing the below error.

workflow_dev=# insert into onyx.result_table (uid, ruleid, date, first_query_result, second_query_result, difference, rule_success_or_fail) values ('',1,"2016-11-08 06:56:49.664711",0,0,'',True);
ERROR:  column "2016-11-08 06:56:49.664711" does not exist in result_table

Below is the table structure:

workflow_dev=# select * from result_table;
 uid | ruleid | date | first_query_result | second_query_result | difference | rule_success_or_fail
-----+--------+------+--------------------+---------------------+------------+----------------------
(0 rows)

The colomn is having date field. But even it is throwing the error. Can anyone help on this ?

Comment: Are you providing single quotes for date value, such as **'2016-11-08 06:56:49.664711'**?

Comment: Am giving single quotes. But now am getting ERROR:  cannot set an identity column to a value

Comment: is column **uid** an identity column? If so then do not provide any value in insert statement.